# Meteor - rendering a blaze template within a react template?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

This should be a simple question -

Say I have a simple Meteor app using the react package.

I have a root.html file and have flow-router which renders a JSX template on the '/' route.

Say I want my JSX template to embed a blaze-template.

How would I do this?

Take for example the following code:

```
# test.js
<template name="Test">
Hello world
</template>
```

...

```
# root.jsx
Root = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      {this.props.content}
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

...

```
# routes.jsx
FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: "root",
  action: function(params, queryParams) {
    ReactLayout.render(Root,
      {content: <Test />})
  }
})
```

But with this code, I get a client-side error about not being able to find `<Test />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah well I figured this out.

I also figured how the inverse (how to render react templates from within blaze)

So to render blaze from react, you make a wrapper class:

```
AccountsWrapper = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    this.view = Blaze.render(Template.Accounts,
      React.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
  },
  componentWillUnmount() {
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
  },
  render() {
    // Just render a placeholder container that will be filled in
    return <span ref="container" />;
  }
});
```

This references a blaze template defined in `accounts.html`:

```
<template name="Accounts">
  {{> loginButtons }}
  <div>
    {{> React component=Test}}
  </div>
</template>
```

In my routes file, I render the wrapper template like so:

```
FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: "root",
  action: function(params, queryParams) {
    ReactLayout.render(Root,
      {content: <AccountsWrapper />})
  }
})
```

You can also see that in my blaze template I'm calling

```
{{> React component=Test}}
```

This depends on the `react-template-helper` package and I wrap the react template using the following code (in JSX:

```
Test = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>
    WORKING
    </div>
  }
})

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.Accounts.helpers({
    Test() {
      return Test;
    }
  })
}
```